# How to integrate refer and earn in android

Tags: android, android-sharing, invite, refer

I am new for android,i am trying to integrate refer and earn option in my app.
plz help me.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_byJB7NePlTZkhaUUw1dGU5ejg

Comment: You need to elaborate more on the nature of your problem and what the question actually is. Users need to log-in to view your Google Drive content, most people won't do this. Provide the content of your question without this kind of external reference. Do some research yourself, also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank for your information

Answer (score 0):

Use Branch, here is the link [Branch.io](https://branch.io). Not only that, you can also track how many of them installed the app by clicking on the link that you or anyone else shared. It generates specific key and track that when you come to app through link.

Comment: @Sajid You're welcome, if you find my info useful please upvote my answer. Thanks.